# In-place editing with find and jq yields inconsistent results

Tags: find, jq

I am trying to use jq to modify a fairly large number of files *if* the file contains a property of a certain value:

```
find . \
    -name '*.configuration.json' \
    -type f -exec bash -c 'jq "select(.version == \"2.0\") | .identifier = \"\"" $0 | sponge "$0"' {} \;
```

So I've learned a fair deal getting here, like how to actually redirect output it in `-exec` and how *not* to redirect output using `jq`.

The above script works for some files found, but other files it just overwrites the entire file with nothing at all. I'm guessing this is caused by a race condition, but I'm at a loss for how I can fix that.

Any help or pointing other pitfalls I might've walked into here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your `jq` expression is that if the `verison` key for a JSON object isn't `2.0`, then that object isn't selected and will not be outputted.  This means you're effectively deleting anything that does not have `2.0` as `version`.

Instead, update the `identifier` value for each object whose `version` is `2.0`:

```bash
jq 'select(.version == "2.0").identifier = ""'
```

The crux is to update the value without extracting it from its object.

One could also use something like the following, which is more like what you have in your code:

```bash
jq 'select(.version == "2.0") |= (.identifier = "")'
```

This uses the update operator, `|=`, to update the objects selected by `select()`.

With `find`:

```bash
find . -name '*.configuration.json' -type f -exec sh -c '
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    for pathname do
        cp -- "$pathname" "$tmpfile" &&
        jq "select(.version == \"2.0\").identifier = \"\"" <"$tmpfile" >"$pathname"
    done
    rm -f "$tmpfile"' sh {} +
```

This also avoids calling the in-line script more times than necessary, and the loop in the `sh -c` script ensures that the permissions and ownership of the original file are retained.

Or, if you want to use `sponge` (which I have never used myself, so consider this an untested example):

```bash
find . -name '*.configuration.json' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        jq "select(.version == \"2.0\").identifier = \"\"" "$pathname" |
        sponge "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Works like a charm and noticeably faster than what I had. Thank you!